# How to convert from ViewPager to ViewPager2

Tags: android

Here the sample code that i want to change to ViewPager2
I have problem at viewPager.setAdapter(adapter) and viewPager.addOnLChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))

This my declaration

```
private ViewPager2 viewPager;


private void setViewPager(){
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_chat));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_request));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_findfriends));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnLChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

}
```

Comment: Check docs: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout you're working with

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@color/colorSurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout">

    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the MainAdapter class

```
class MainAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifeCycle: Lifecycle
): FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifeCycle) {

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position) {
            0 -> FragmentOne()
            else -> FragmentTwo()
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 2
}
```

This is your MainFragment.

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val tabList = arrayOf("Fragment One", "Fragment Two")

        viewPager.adapter = MainAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab: TabLayout.Tab, position: Int ->
            tab.text = tabList[position]
        }.attach()

    }
}
```

You can now go ahead and create your FragmentOne and FragmentTwo.